# Is there any way to identify a users ranking on the site? (within a particular tag?)

Tags: feature-request, user-rank

I have noticed that some users have taken it upon themselves to create [websites](http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/default.aspx) that allow you to see a user's rank (percentile) among SO developers.  I like this.  I was wondering if the owners of the website are planning something like this in the future?  If so, are you planning on making this by tag?  (I care less about where I rank when compared to developers of a different language).

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
C#:      User is ranked #XX (Top XX %)
ASP.Net: User is ranked #YY (Top YY %)
```

Comment: Rankings filtering inactive users would be more interesting, though active is subjective.

Answer (score 4):

The app you're referring to is called SOrep and its details are available here: [SOREP: Trilogy Site Ranking - For those who need to know](https://stackapps.com/questions/543/)

Have you thought about using the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to calculate the tag percentage?

Comment: The actual question was `I was wondering if the owners of the website are planning something like this in the future?`. The author has already found sites that do the user's rank and is wondering if that will become native. This does not address that....

Comment: Although by using the Data Explorer, it would seem that I get what I'm looking for, the problem is that by running my own query, I lose credibility (even if the query was written correctly).  I need the information to come from the website itself, so that anyone who looked at the result would be more able to trust it.

Comment: @Gabriel: the Data Explorer is an official part of the StackExchange network. What do you mean by "the website itself"?

Comment: By "the website itself," I mean a page or an API provided by the website, where the code is out of my control.  The value of this is to showcase my rank among other developers.  I could write a script myself in the Data Explorer, but I could purposely write a script that makes me look better than I am.  You wouldn't trust a political candidate to calculate the winner in their own election, would you?

Comment: @Gabriel: You can't change the data in the Data Explorer. It's dumped directly from the StackExchange sites and is read-only.

Comment: data is data... the result of the script (any script) is another thing entirely... If I wrote the script, then how would anyone know whether or not I had written tricks to make my numbers look better (EX: select reputation + 10000 as reputation)

Comment: @Gabriel: Uh... because they can see the script?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if you really don't understand, or if you're just trying to argue.  Anyone would understand that an official number is more trustworthy than a number that was returned by a script written by the person who stands to benefit from one result over another.  Its just common sense.